# Getting MQHRF2 MQMD header instead of MQRFH2,Middleware team getting MQHRF2 instead of MQRFH2 from Spring JMS IBM MQ

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, mq

I am using Spring JMS IBM MQ for connecting SAP bapi service but while sending jms messageit automatically create MQMD header as MQHRF2 instead of MQRFH2 according to middleware team which is not correct. So request you to please help in this.,I am using Spring JMS IBM MQ for connecting the SAP BAPI services so that I am sending the jms message to middleware but they are getting MQHRF2 header instead of MQRFH2. So for changing this what I have to do??? I tried to set non jms (MQSTR) but still it is sending MQHRF2 only.

Comment: Clarify your question please , does the middleware team need MQRFH2 (Middleware parsing using JMS Nodes perhaps in WMB) or headers or MQSTR headers (Parsing using MQ Nodes) ? As i understand you are sending MQRFH2 and the middleware needs MQSTR ? If you are using JMS how are you doing JNDI lookup for QCF and Queues ?

Comment: Middleware expecting MQRFH2 but from our spring coding side it is creating MQHRF2. I tried to set using MQMD format propert but still it is sending MQHRF2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those things the IBM MQ team did that always causes confusion with newbies.

An 'MQRFH2' is a structure with a header and 1 or more 'folders'.  It is placed in front of your message data (payload).

The MQMessage's MD has a field called 'format' and when you have a message which contains an MQRFH2 structure, the MD's format has a value of 'MQHRF2  ' (8 chars).

So, a properly created MQ/JMS aka (MQRFH2 message) will have the message's MD format field with a value of 'MQHRF2  '.

Therefore, you are sending a properly formatted message - you are just getting confused because of IBM's weirdness.

Note: They did the same thing with other internal message structures.  i.e. MQIIH uses MQIMS format, MQCIH uses MQCICS format, etc.

Comment: Thank you Roger, but middleware team is expecting MQRFH2 for calling SAP bapi service so is there any way that we can set or middleware team has to change at their end?

Comment: There is no such thing as an MQRFH2 message that has an MD format field set to 'MQRFH2'.  An MQRFH2 message (aka JMS) MUST have the MD format field set to 'MQHRF2 '.  The middleware team clearly does not understand MQ.  Read this IBM Support doc: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27017014 It talks about viewing an MQRFH2 message. Scroll down to the amqsbcg display of a message and you will see the Format : 'MQHRF2  ' in BOLD.

Comment: Thank you so much Roger, we got same response from IBM as well.